# Correctly applying rules of differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be:

$$
     f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} \frac{x^3-\sqrt{2e^x}}{3x^3}, & x>0 \\
         -x^2+2x^4-7, & x=0 \\
x^3-4e^2x, & x < 0.
\end{array}\right .
$$

If I want to analyze rigorously where $f$ is differentiable I would do it as follows:

As $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$ is an open set we can apply the rules of differentiation (quotient rule, chain rule etc...) to $f_{\vert \mathbb{R_{>0}}}$ and hence $f$ is differentiable on the restriction  $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$. Then I apply the same reasoning to $f_{\vert \mathbb{R_{<0}}}$. Although $f(x)=x^2+2x^4-7$ looks nice and smoothly, I mustn't apply the rules of differentiation to $f(x)=x^2+2x^4-7$ as it is only defined like this on an isolated point and not an open set. So I have to check the limit of the differential quotient to correctly prove if $f$ is differentiable or not on this restriction.

I don't want to calculate the limit but can you give me a quick feedback on whether I have understood it correctly or not? I am not 100% sure if it is right to say that I mustn't apply the rules of differentiation to $f$ where it is only restricted on a sigle point.

Any comments are appreciated

Comment: You are definitely correct that you cannot apply any “rules” to the polynomial given in the definition of $f$ for $x=0$, because that expression could be replaced by any expression that evaluates to -7, including just the number -7, without changing the function.

Comment: You know that $f(0) = -7$, and how $f$ is defined on intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. All that is missing is to see if they glue well together on $x=0$. This means checking if the lateral limits are $-7$ (which would show that the function is continuous on $0$) and if the lateral limits of the derivative of $f$ coincide with one another (that is, the tangent at zero is well defined, and not some function like $x \mapsto |x|$).

Comment: This function is clearly not differentiable at $x=0$ because $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty$

Comment: The line "$-x^2+ 2x^4- 7$, x= 0" is peculiar.  Why not just "-7"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

Checking differentiability (and if applicable evaluating the derivative) of f in some point x is equivalent to doing so for $f|_N$ for some open neighbourhood N of x. This is because we only need to consider an arbitrarily small neighbourhood of x when checking the convergence of the difference quotient of f in x (since the limit is $\tilde{x} \xrightarrow{} x$).  That is why you can apply the rules of differentiation to any open set.

For points where this is not helpful (i.e., x=0 in your example) you still need to "manually check" differentiability with the definition, i.e., check the convergence of the difference quotient in x.

You probably know that differentiable functions are always continuous. If f is not continuous in x then it is not differentiable in x either. This is often easier to see then the divergence of the difference quotient (in your example f(0)=-7 but clearly $\lim_{x \uparrow 0}f(x)=0$ so the question of differentiablity in 0 is easy to answer).